# Cannot use Scanner to read only one line at a time in Java

Tags: java, file-io, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read a file line by line in java. Here is my code:

```
Scanner s= new Scanner(new FileReader("outputfile.txt"));
    String line = null;
    while (!(line = s.nextLine()).contains("OK")) {
        if (line.contains("BOOK")) {
            //do something
        }   
    }
```

What i am trying to do is, i read the file line by line, and if the next line has "OK" in it, then i stop reading. But the problem is, since i have

```
!(line = s.nextLine()).contains("OK")
```

every time i get into the line

```
if (line.contains("BOOK")),
```

since line=s.nextLine() 
i read another line and in one loop cycle i read two lines. How can i fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how the `=` operator works.

```
line = s.nextLine()
```

does not mean that every time you use `line`, it calls `s.nextLine()`. Rather,

```
line = s.nextLine()
```

means "call `s.nextLine()` once, and make `line` refer to what `s.nextLine()` returned". Thus,

```
if (line.contains("BOOK"))
```

does not cause another call to `s.nextLine()`. It only looks up the value stored in `line` by the previous assignment. The loop reads one line per iteration, not two. If you tried it, and it seemed to skip lines, that's probably because "BOOK" contains "OK", so the code in the `if` never runs.

Comment: you are right, it is supposed to be like you said but something weird is happening at it makes no sense. I tried it with other words different from OK and BOOK and still same errors happen. i will try to clean project and then rebuild it

Answer (score 0):

Let's unfold the code for clarity:

```
while (true) {
  line = s.nextLine();
  if (line == null || line.contains("OK")) break;
  if (line.contains("BOOK")) { ... }
}
```

Unfortunately `"BOOK"` and `"OK"` inside it, so the second condition is unreachable.

You need to look a little more closely at the syntax of the file to parse this correctly.

Comment: If the OK or BOOK were the first or last element of the line, methods like startsWith( ) could help a lot.

Comment: that is really weird, when i debug, i see that every time i get to the other line in java code, next line is read. For example when i go from line if(....) to else if(...) one more line is read even though there is no read command

Comment: unfortunately they are not

Answer (score 0):

Think about what you are doing here...

```
// LOOP
// Read the next line
// Does this line contain "OK"
      // YES -> End loop
      // NO  -> Does the line contain "BOOK" - Obviously it cant if it didn't contain "OK"
      //     -> BACK TO LOOP
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
while (s.hasNextLine()) {
      String line = s.nextLine();
      if (line.contains("BOOK")) {
          ...
      } else if (line.contains("OK") {
         break;
      }
}
```

Comment: that is really weird, when i debug, i see that every time i get to the other line in java code, next line is read. For example when i go from line if(....) to else if(...) one more line is read even though there is no read command

Comment: @bigO, since only the `if` or the `else` can run for each loop, `s.nextLine()` must have been run between the 2 statements.